# Single-category column chart in Highcharts 3.0 beta

Tags: highcharts

I am using a single xAxis category and 4 discrete data series (each one containing a single data item). Unfortunately, when I try to construct a simple ColumnChart using Highcharts 3.0 beta, the chart is never displayed:

```
chartB = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'containerB',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan' //Just one category
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
                series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9] //One data point for each series element.

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4]

            }]
        });
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/7CJhf/5/.

A workaround is to append an empty category ('') and a zero value to each series item, but this moves the column set to the left. Is there any proper workaround to create a column chart with Highcharts 3.0 beta, using single data points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this issue before [issue 1535](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1535#issuecomment-13940507) with a stacked column of length 1. This is fixed in the lastest master branch [highchart.src.js](https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/js/highcharts.src.js) and [highcharts-more.src.js](https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/js/highcharts-more.src.js). Try updating the script-references to the raw github references here, and it should work ok.

Comment: That's true - it's already fixed issue on mater branch, example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/7CJhf/6/